# No QNetworkConfiguration although I can connect to WIFI

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

On my Laptop (Qt 5.11, Win10 x64) I am connected via WIFI, Qt https connections work. I wonder why I do not see any active network configurations, but can create HTTP requests. Also `m_networkConfigManager->isOnline()` is always `false`. Am I missing something, or is this just a Qt bug?

```
// signal / slot
connect(m_networkConfigManager, &QNetworkConfigurationManager::updateCompleted, this, &CApplication::onNetworkConfigurationsUpdateCompleted, Qt::QueuedConnection);

// called via signal
void CApplication::onNetworkConfigurationsUpdateCompleted()
{
    const QNetworkConfiguration config = m_networkConfigManager->defaultConfiguration();
    for (const QNetworkConfiguration &config : m_networkConfigManager->allConfigurations())
    {
        // never reached
        const QString cs = CNetworkUtils::toString(config);
        CLogMessage(this).info("Network config: %1") << cs;
    }

    // always false
    bool isOnline = m_networkConfigManager->isOnline();
    .... debug messages, I see onNetworkConfigurationsUpdateCompleted being called 3 times
    ....
}
```

--- edit ---

- I see `onNetworkConfigurationsUpdateCompleted` being called 3 times and then somehow periodically every 10 secs.
- after I init `m_networkConfigManager` I call `m_networkConfigManager->updateConfigurations();`

--- edit 2 ---

This version yields the same result (false) (not Queued)

```
connect(m_networkConfigManager, &QNetworkConfigurationManager::updateCompleted, [ = ]
{
   bool isOnline = m_networkConfigManager->isOnline();
   qDebug() << isOnline;
});
```

and this is never called

```
connect(m_networkConfigManager, &QNetworkConfigurationManager::onlineStateChanged, [](bool isOnline)
{
    qDebug() << isOnline; // never get here
});
```

--- edit 3 ---

Follow up question: [Disable Qt bearer management at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824242/disable-qt-bearer-management-at-runtime)

Comment: May I suggest you to connect `QNetworkConfigurationManager::onlineStateChanged` to a slot/lambda with a debug message and see if it changes at all.

Comment: If the question is whether `onNetworkConfigurationsUpdateCompleted` is called, then YES, I can see it in the debugger being called 3-4 times, also I see my debug messages which are just now shown in the code segment above. Updated the question, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Actually, my idea was more in the following direction: could `isOnline` become `true` for a short time and then go back to `false` by the time you query it?

Comment: updated the code above, onlineChanged actually never triggers something in my very scenario. btw, with a cable connection via LAN it works .

Comment: To me it looks like you've done everything right, but it doesn't behave as expected. Maybe you should report it to Qt as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

As of the Qt bug tracking system most likely a Qt bug. The whole bearer system seems to be broken for WIFI, or at least being not very reliable. It is a bit hard to trace since there are different issues in different Qt versions depending on the platform (OS).

- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-40332
- https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65586

I am using a simple hack workaround (bad practice, but working). If there is no network configuration this could mean I run into that issue, or there is no network interface at all. In that very case I just set the `QAM` to `Accessible` and test via a http request. If it works WIFI is available.

```
const QList<QNetworkConfiguration> allConfigurations = m_networkConfigManager->allConfigurations();
if (allConfigurations.isEmpty()) {
    m_accessManager->setNetworkAccessible(QNetworkAccessManager::Accessible);`
    .... test Qt http request ....     
}
```