# Disable Qt bearer management at runtime

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qtplugin

We have some problems with the Qt network bearer management (Win10 x64, Qt 5.9.latest). The following problems are noticed:

- a WIFI interface is not recognized
- a WIFI interface is marked as inaccessible though working (QAM requests work)
- cable LAN is not affected

To some extend **I simply can fix the issue by deleting the** `bearer` **folder** from my distribution. I understand I can compile a Qt version without bearer management, but this is a precompiled Win64 version with just a deleted `bearer`folder now.

1. Can I somehow disable the bearer management dynamically at runtime?
2. Is deleting the folder risky? It seems to work for our application, but is there some expected side effect which will kill the application?

For us it was working with the bearer management of 5.6.x, now is broken with 5.9.x, my 5.11.x IDE version (I use for development) still seems to be broken.

--- edit ----

With bearer and WIFI and cable I see (the WIFI adapter is connected but not shown)

```
18:56:11 info: Network report:
1: Ethernet 287176533 valid: yes Active, Discovered, Defined InternetAccessPoint
QAM: Accessible: yes (Accessible) config: Ethernet 287176533 valid: yes Active, Discovered, Defined InternetAccessPoint
```

Without bearer no network configs are shown and the QAM reports "not accessible" (but works)

```
19:00:40 info: Network report:
No network configurations!
QAM: Accessible: no (NotAccessible) config:   valid: no Undefined Invalid
```

With bearer and WIFI only (working) it looks like without bearer:

```
19:10:42 info: Network report:
No network configurations!
QAM: Accessible: no (NotAccessible) config:   valid: no Undefined Invalid
```

Comment: The Qt bug report: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-68613